# Finding limit in two-dimensional space

Tags: limits, analysis

Find the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,\pi/2)} \sec x \cdot \tan y$.

I tried to use $y=mx$. But, I didn't solve it. And then I tried to use half-angle formulas it didn't work either. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Approach $(0, \pi/2)$ along two different directions on the vertical line $x = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I solved the question!